# Upgrading from .NET 6 to 7

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-7.0

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.6

Listing NET SDKs installed gives:

```
C:\Users\User>dotnet --list-sdks    
2.1.520 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    
2.2.108 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    
5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    
6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    
7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Listing runtimes also show 7.0.

But none of the projects can see it.

[image: NET 7.0 is missing from the list]

Comment: What if u changed the SDK version in the csproj file?

Comment: Also try using the VS installer to install 7.0

Comment: If I change the version in the SCProj, as suggested in all the tutorials on how to upgrade, it fails to build and says the project file is corrupted.

Comment: @BWhite Could you post the code of your .csproj file?

Comment: I think the problem was the version of VS. I thought 2022 was sufficient, especially since I only upgraded recently. But I was on v 17.2. 17.7 shows 7.0 as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought having VS2022 was sufficient.
But I was on v 17.2.
17.7 now shows 7.0 as an option.